# SSL Handshake in Android via Bluetooth Classic

Tags: android, openssl, bluetooth, handshake

I am working on implementing an Android App (client) which will be connected to Raspberry Pi (server) via Bluetooth Classic.
To make data transfer securely, I want to implement SSL encryption between client and server.
I have created the Bluetooth socket and connected to the server successfully.
To establish a secure connection, I would like to complete the SSL handshake process between client and the server.
After creating the bluetooth socket am unable to add the SSL Socket to the bluetooth socket to complete the handshake.

I would like to know how can we add SSLSocket to a BluetoothSocket to complete the handshake and transfer the data between client and the server securely.
I saw the C example from the link below and implemented the server using C in Raspberry Pi.
https://github.com/zapstar/two-way-ssl-c
I want to mimic the client in Android Mobile App.
Thanks for the response. Appreciate it.

Please find the below code implementation.

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
@SuppressLint("Assert")
  ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
  bluetoothDevice = device;
  try {
    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    Log.d( TAG, "Trying to open the socket to " + bluetoothDevice.getAddress() );
    String privateMethod = "createRfcommSocket";
    Method m = bluetoothDevice.getClass().getMethod( privateMethod, int.class );
    bluetoothSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke( bluetoothDevice, 1 );
    assert bluetoothSocket != null;
    bluetoothSocket.connect(); // socket opened successfully
    Log.d( TAG, "bluetoothSocket: "+  bluetoothSocket.isConnected() );
  } catch ( Exception connectException ) {
  // Unable to connect; close the socket and return.
  try {
   Log.d( TAG, "connectException: "+connectException );
   if( bluetoothSocket != null ) {
     bluetoothSocket.close();
   }
  } catch (IOException closeException) {
   Log.e( TAG, "Could not close the client socket: " + closeException );
 }
 return;
 } finally {
   try {
     if( bluetoothSocket != null ) {
         bluetoothSocket.close();
     }
   } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
}
@SuppressLint("Assert")
public void run() {
    InputStream mInputStream = null;
    OutputStream mOutputStream = null;
        try {
            // DO THE SSL HANDSHAKE HERE AND THEN WRITE DATA TO SERVER USING OUTPUT STREAM

            TlsSocketFactory tlsSocketFactory = new TlsSocketFactory();
            SSLContext sslContext = tlsSocketFactory.getSSLContext(getApplicationContext());
            
            // How to convert a BluetoothSocket to Socket to make handshake successful
            Socket socket = new Socket( bluetoothDevice.getAddress(), 1 );
            SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, null, 1 ,false);

            sslsocket.setUseClientMode( true );
            sslsocket.startHandshake();

            Log.d(TAG, "SSL Handshake Successful");

            try {
                BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( sslsocket.getInputStream() ) );
                String response = null;
                while ((response = read.readLine()) != null)
                    Log.d( TAG, response );
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e);
            }

            String outputString = "appdata";
            Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
            byte[] byteArray = outputString.getBytes(charset);

            mOutputStream = sslsocket.getOutputStream();
            mOutputStream.write(byteArray);
            mOutputStream.flush();

            Log.d(TAG, "bluetoothDevice.getBondState(): " + bluetoothDevice.getBondState() + ",bluetoothSocket.isConnected(): " + bluetoothSocket.isConnected() );

        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e );
                assert false;
                if( mInputStream != null )
                    mInputStream.close();
                assert false;
                if( mOutputStream != null )
                    mOutputStream.close();
                if( bluetoothSocket != null )
                    bluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
                closeException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: This is a pure programming problem and not a security problem, i.e. off-topic here.

Comment: I have added in stackoverflow as well. Thought some one from security might help me out.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65412848/ssl-handshake-in-android-via-bluetooth-classic    Thanks.